# Xcode doesn't see AVCaptureSession Preset

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I have upgraded my Xcode(10.1) to newest version.
In one of my project I wanted to set cameraSession preset, but 
it not see it. I have started it on Xcode 9.x.x.

```
AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
```

> Type 'AVCaptureSession.Preset' (aka 'NSString') has no member 'photo'

Although on my another project( started - Xcode 10.0) it has no error and I able to set preset.
I have tried change build settings to legacy mode but it didn't helped.

Comment: What is your minimum deployment target?

Comment: What is the swift version you are using ?